# HTML PHP File Upload Error

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload a PDF file, but getting the "Invalid File" error. I have used the code from w3schools, but its not working. Here is the PHP code

```
    $allowedExts = array("pdf");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["pdfFile"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
    && ($_FILES["pdfFile"]["size"] < 1200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["pdfFile"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["pdfFile"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("../assets/pdf/" . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfFile"]["tmp_name"],
          "../assets/pdf/" . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "../assets/pdf/" . $_FILES["pdfFile"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in `<form>` section from your HTML

Comment: First `var_dump($_FILES["pdfFile"])`. There could be 3 problems: 1. `type != "application/pdf"` 2. File size > 1200000 3. Extension not allowed. I think you forgot to set the enctype on the form.

Comment: You should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag to upload a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just check (by `echo`, `var_dump` or whatever suits you) the content of `$_FILES["pdfFile"]` ? Are you sure it fits ?

And you did set the enctype of Your upload form as well ?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

And the form method is equal POST ?

Comment: In this case You are uploading the file with diffrent name, just check content of `$_FILES` array and You will get Your answer easly. Next just swap the 'pdfFile' with the new name and Your good to go.

Comment: @NiteshYadav Check if the file element name is same as what you have in PHP i.e. `pdfFile`

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a problem with file permissions?

Check if you have permission to write to folder `../assets/pdf/`.

Comment: He dont even reach that part of code so how can this be a problem ?

Comment: You're right. It's hard to see with this indent and improper error checking.

Comment: Yes no offence just want to make all the doubts cleared. Cheers.